# inheritance of Has-a relation

Tags: c++, oop

I was reading about Has-a and Is-a relation in here: [What do “has-a” and “is-a” mean? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677545/what-do-has-a-and-is-a-mean)
 
. What I understand is that my data members of the class follow the Has-a relation. Let's say that I inherit data members from the Base class. Are they still going to follow Has-a relation? 
in this example: Car is-a vehicle. Is it still going to have a steering wheel?

```
class SteeringWheel
{};

class Vehicle
{

public:
SteeringWheel  sWheel;
virtual void doStuff() = 0;

};

class Car: public Vehicle
{

virtual void doStuff();

};
```

Comment: Yes, `Car` *has a* `SteeringWheel`. Inheritance makes the child-classes inherit *everything* from the base-class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both is-a and has-a relations are *transitional*. That means, you cannot say, for example, that

`Car` is-a `Vehicle` (which has-a `SteeringWheel`) *except* it does not have-a `SteeringWheel`.

or

`Car` is-a `Vehicle` (which is-a `Machine`) *except* it is-not-a `Machine`.

Having to implement the above examples would mean that your design is flawed. This would essentially go against the [Open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) - you simply should not *take away* from a base class (or ignore the existence of some of its parts), only *extend* it by inheritance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What i am trying to understand is why the example above goes against Open-closed principle. If we would like to extend the inheritance, then all the vehicles will have a steering wheel without changing the base class. what am i missing?

Comment: @ValeriGrishin LogicStuff didn't say you are wrong (or that your example violates open-closed), they just provided some examples of where problems could occur. As long as all your vehicles are guaranteed to have steering wheels, having a base class `Vehicle` with a member `SteeringWheel` is perfectly fine. But note that `AirBalloon` should not inherit from `Vehicle` then because `AirBalloon` should not have a `SteeringWheel` member.